# Indefinite integration: $\int x^{x^2+1}(2\ln x+1)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

Find the value of the integral: $$\int x^{x^2+1}(2\ln x+1)dx.$$
My attempt: I tried by using integration by parts, but not working since $x^{x^2+1}$ keeps coming again and again.

Then I tried putting $x^{x^2+1}=t$, this also is not helpful. Can someone help me in solving this question?

Comment: Hint:  Compute the derivative of $x^{x^2+1}$ (it will still need some work after that though).

Comment: @lulu,derivative of $x^{x^2+1} $ is $x^{x^2+2}(2lnx+1)+x^{x^2}$

Comment: This has (somehow) become a hot question. People coming in remember upvotes must be genuinely good question, not a common homework integral.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the integral
$$\int x^{x^2+1} \, (2\ln x+1) \, dx$$
let $u = x^{2} \, \ln x$ for which $du = (2x \, \ln x + x ) \, dx$ and 
\begin{align}
I &= \int x^{x^{2} + 1} \, (2 \, \ln x + 1) \, dx \\
&= \int e^{x^{2} \, \ln x} \, (2 x \, \ln x + x) \, dx \\
&= \int e^{u} \, du \\
&= e^{u} + c_{0} \\
&= e^{x^{2} \, \ln x} + c_{0} = x^{x^{2}} + c_{0}.
\end{align}
Hence
$$\int x^{x^2+1} \, (2\ln x+1) \, dx = x^{x^{2}} + c_{0}.$$

Comment: Better than mine!  +1

Answer (score 5):

Observe that

$$x^{x^2+1}(2\log x+1)=x^{x^2}(2x\log x+x)=x^{x^2}\left(\frac{d\,\log x^{x^2}}{dx}\right)=\frac{d\,x^{x^2}}{dx}$$

Thus,

$$\int x^{x^2+1}(2\log x+1)dx=x^{x^2}+C$$

Comment: Great minds. Our solutions represent two methods of view to learn from

Comment: @Leucippus Thanks! And I see what you did there.

Comment: @Leucippus  Edited... and +1 for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^{x^2}=t\implies (x^{x^2}(2x)\ln x+x^2x^{x^2-1})dx=dt$ $$x^{x^2+1}(2\ln x+1)dx=dt$$ Hence, we have $$\int x^{x^2+1}(2\ln x+1)dx=\int dt$$$$=t+C$$ $$=x^{x^2}+C$$